# Determine when UIView has finished layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have UIView subclass, and for laying out UI elements i don't using Auto Layout. I want to set frame depends on width or height of frame. However, when i do this right after `alloc]init]` methods, it look like self.frame.size.height or width is zero. For temporary solution i did following:

```
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_level_arrow"];
        _arrowImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
        _arrowImgView.center = CGPointMake(self.mainImgView.frame.size.width/2, self.mainImgView.frame.size.height-2);
        _arrowImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_level_arrow"];
        _arrowImgView.contentMode   = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [self.mainImgView addSubview:_arrowImgView];
    });
```

But of course i need to know, when view is finish loading and where it has actual self.frame.size.width and height.

Comment: Have you looked at `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;`? Apple ref: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews?language=objc

Comment: @DonMag That's for a view controller, not a view.

Comment: Does your initializer actually set the size of self?

Comment: If you just googled here trying to do in UIView what you can do in a view controller, in *some* cases `didMoveToSuperview` is the solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to do this in your custom view subclass, override `layoutSubviews` in that class. Since iOS may send `layoutSubviews` more than once, be careful to only create `_arrowImgView` the first time:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (_arrowImgView == nil) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_level_arrow"];
        _arrowImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        _arrowImgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [self addSubview:_arrowImgView];
    }

    CGRect myBounds = self.bounds;
    CGRect mainFrame = self.mainImageView.frame;
    _arrowImgView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, myBounds.size.width, myBounds.size.height);
    _arrowImgView.center = CGPointMake(mainFrame.size.width / 2, mainFrame.size.height - 2);
}
```

Comment: I find it odd that you recommend creating and adding subviews in `layoutSubviews`. Shouldn't that be done in the appropriate `init` method? `layoutSubviews` should do just that - layout the subviews. It's not the place to create, show, hide, or alter subviews other than setting their frames.

Comment: Allow me to quote [the “Tweaking the Layout of Your Views Manually” section of the View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW48): “Your implementation of this method can do any of the following: … Add or remove subviews or Core Animation layers.”

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't noticed that before. I've spent the last decade thinking that method should only be used to set frames.

Comment: That said, I'd usually create and add the subview in `init`.

Comment: @robmayoff it does work, but i wonder why such simple thing is so complicated. Maybe it's good idea to create subclass of UIView and using KVO check whether it views have width & height greater then 0, then send fire notificiation and invoke method like "viewDidFinishLayoutItSubviews* and unsubscribe to notification. I use KVO mechanics to check when tableView finish load and have size greater then 0.

Comment: I think that suggestion by Apple is really horrible.  For example, most beginners would make the mistake of adding something there, and it would then be added "over and over" ...

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, in some cases `didMoveToSuperview` is the solution.

Comment: @Fattie The frame and bounds may be .zero when `didMoveToSuperView` is called.

Comment: "be careful to only create _arrowImgView the first time"  Use a lazy property

Comment: @Womble that's why I said "in some cases"  :) also, using didMoveToSuperview has many complicatoins, you have to check wher ethe hell it moved to (posisbly nil) etc

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban you just use lazy vars for layers, the normal idiom

Answer (score 2):

Use this one. It handles orientation changes, and redrawing of Gradient background.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
final class GradientButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
    @IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        if let gradient = layer.sublayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer {
            gradient.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.frame.size)
        gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

        super.draw(rect)
    }

   @IBInspectable var imageContentMode: Int {
        get {
            return imageView?.contentMode.rawValue ?? 0
        }
        set {
            imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode(rawValue: newValue) ?? .scaleAspectFit

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't remember the WWDC but Apple said not to add layers/views in drawRect. The idea is to configure those elements, then let the layout and rendering passes handle them.

Comment: this is just totally wrong, as Wombie says. you're adding tens or thousands of layers

Comment: they are removed then added

Answer (score 2):

When the final size of the view is required for 'layer operations' such as adding borders, you can use(in swift 4):

```
override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
    // 'layer operations'
}
```

I was working on adding a border only to the bottom through a function,
I had an issue where the border was shorter than the final width of the button.

I'm leaving this for those who faced the same problem and tried `layoutSubviews` but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

##### A handy trick based on the excellent @Walue answer:

As a quick solution, you likely have zillions of lines of existing code in

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    ... masses of code
    ... masses of code
}
```

and associated functions, lazy layers, etc etc.

A quick way to implement the "Walue fix" is just:

add this ...

```
var NOTYET = true
override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
    NOTYET = false
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    if NOTYET { return }

    ... masses of code
    ... masses of code
}
```

Your sensitive code will now wait until the layout constraints solver, etc, etc, has done it's work.

Answer (score -9):

viewWillLayoutSubviews and last one viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   // your code for positioning any subview here
}
```

Comment: This is for a view controller, not a view.

Comment: please check the difference between UIView and ViewController. I suggest you have to look at @IBDesignables where you have to call this method inside your UIView hope I was clear enough